# Android: clicking noise is heard on headphone while playing audio when phone moves

Tags: android, audio, noise, headphones, clicking

I have written an Android app that receives audio from WiFi and plays it. When the phone is still and not moving the audio quality is great. But when I move the phone specially when it is connected to a headphone I can hear clicking noise. I am wondering if this is something known that can be mitigated in the App? For example since Android knows if the headphone is connected or not, if the jack is not very stable and shaky it could create some interrupts and cause this clicking noise? By the way the phone that I am doing the testing on is HTC Inspire 4g.

Comment: My initial thought is a hardware issue.  Try a different phone, different headphones, playing local instead of over wifi, etc.

Comment: Even if the phone is a problem there is clearly an interrupt due   to the fact that phone thinks the headphone gets disconnected. Is there any way to disable this kind of interrupt?

Comment: Good point. When I play local audio I don't see this issue, so this means there is something related to my app.

Comment: So anyone has any idea what might cause this in an app? Is there any way to make an app unsensitive to plug in and out of headphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For benefit of others:
It looks like after some investigation it is not the headphone jack, but the wifi link that changes. When I hold the phone in my hand and move it quickly it looks like the wifi link gets very weak for a short period of time and I loose the link for some time and that causes the clicking noise.